# $(ℤ/mℤ)/(\bar n) ≅ℤ/nℤ$ with $n|m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I'm trying to proof that
>
> $$(ℤ/mℤ)/(\bar n) ≅ℤ/nℤ$$
>
> with $n|m$.

A $m=kn$, we have that:

$$ℤ/mℤ=\{\bar 0,...,\bar n,...,\overline {c(n-1)}\}$$

If the equality: $\bar n = \bar 0$ holds, then obviously we can write this set as:

$$\{\bar 0, \bar 1 ,...,\overline{n-1}\}$$

Some part of me says, this is completely trivial, this is the proof, but an other part of me says I need to show a lot more to make this rigorous. Which part is right ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it more rigorous then define a map from one group to the other and prove it is a homomorphic bijection.

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting caught in notation, which is making your proof a bit opaque. Because $n | m$, you can consider the reduction map $\mathbb{Z}/m\to\mathbb{Z}/n$. Now what is its kernel?