# $(ℤ/mℤ)/(\bar n)$ when $n\nmid m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

I understand that $(ℤ/mℤ)/(\bar n) ≅ℤ/nℤ$ (as rings) when $n\mid m$. (This is also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533712/195021)).

I was wondering (having initiated from a quite different problem) what happens when $n \nmid m$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rewrite the ideal $(\bar n)$ as $(n\mathbb Z + m\mathbb Z)/m\mathbb Z$. One then has $$(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)/(\bar n)=\frac{\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z+m\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z}\cong\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z+m\mathbb Z}=\frac{\mathbb Z}{\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)\mathbb Z}.$$

Comment: nice! so, if $m,n$ are coprime, the quotient is zero right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.